# getting content between two tags XML using jdom

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

i'm trying to get content between tag `<catalog> </catalog>` as this is xml file :

```
<test1>
</test1>
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author> 
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title> 
  <genre>Computer</genre> 
  <price>44.95</price> 
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author> 
  <title>Midnight Rain</title> 
  <genre>Fantasy</genre> 
  <price>5.95</price> 
  </book>
</catalog>
```

and getting as result only this  :

```
<book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author> 
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title> 
      <genre>Computer</genre> 
      <price>44.95</price> 
      </book>
      <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author> 
      <title>Midnight Rain</title> 
      <genre>Fantasy</genre> 
      <price>5.95</price> 
      </book>
```

i begin to learn about jdom ,but i can reach this result i only know basics operations , could any one have an idea about how to do it , and thanks in advance. 
i try this :

```
public static void read() throws JDOMException, IOException{
        SAXBuilder reader = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = reader.build(new File("C:\\Users\\HC\\Desktop\\dataset\\book.xml"));
        racine = doc.getRootElement();

        String root = racine.getName();
        Element catalog = racine.getChild("catalog");
        List nodes = catalog.getChildren();
        Iterator i = nodes.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            Element courant = (Element) i.next();
         // i want here keeping all tags inside the tag catalog
         System.out.print(courant.getContent());

        }

    }
```

i got only result like this :

```
[[Text: 
      ], [Element: <author/>], [Text: 
      ], [Element: <title/>], [Text: 
      ], [Element: <genre/>], [Text: 
      ], [Element: <price/>], [Text: 

   ]][[Text: 
      ], [Element: <author/>], [Text: 
      ], [Element: <title/>], [Text: 
      ], [Element: <genre/>], [Text: 
      ], [Element: <price/>], [Text:
```

Comment: What is the code that you're using to get the result?

Comment: But that is the content of the `<catalog>` element! What result did you expect?

Comment: i added the code i wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code of how to do it with [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net)

```
  import com.ximpleware.*;
    public class getContent {
        public static void main(String s[]) throws VTDException{
            VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
            if (!vg.parseFile("C:\\Users\\HC\\Desktop\\dataset\\book.xml", false))
                return;
            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "book")){
                long l = vn.getContentFragment();
                System.out.println( "book content ==> ");
                System.out.println(vn.toString((int)l, (int)(l<<32)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try with

```
List list = catalog.getChildren("book");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

       Element node = (Element) list.get(i);

       System.out.println("Author : " +node.getChildText("author"));
       System.out.println("Title : " + node.getChildText("title"));
       // ... etc

    }
```

Comment: i dont want to specify the name of child nodes :/ i want do it automaticlly :(